# Automator "New File" workflow in Mojave returning “Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events.”

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I have copied a workflow to [create a new file](https://zeldor.biz/2017/12/mac-os-x-finder-new-file/) from within the finder, saved in ~/Library/Services/. It runs fine from Automator and appears in the Finder > Services menu, but there's no "services" menu when clicking in a blank area within a folder.

I'd expect to right-click on a blank space in a folder (or the desktop) and use the contextual menu and activate it.

The main issue is that the script runs fine from within Automator, but not from the Finder:

> The action “Run AppleScript” encountered an error: “Not authorised to send Apple events to System Events.”

Has anyone else had this issues with a working script?

Comment: NOTE: for now I've used "New File Menu Free" from the App store

Comment: In **macOS Mojave** after creating the **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ based on the link in your question and adding the _keyboard shortcut_ of **⇧⌥⌘F** in **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Services**, I then had to respond to three **Security & Privacy** related _dialog boxes_ when I first ran the **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_. I then had go to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and check **[√] Finder**.

Comment: The **Automator** _Service/Quick Action_ then ran with either the _keyboard shortcut_ or from the **Services** menu and created the _text file_, however there is one issue which I haven't troubleshot yet. When the file is created, it opens the _edit field_ to rename the _file_ but not the one it just created, another one next to it while in _list_ view in **Finder**.

Comment: I think you can add a .4s delay to prevent that selection issue. Thanks for testing: I had those warnings on the first attempt, but initially clicked the wrong option. On recreating the file and trying again, I wasn't offered the initial message again, so got stuck.

Answer (score 1):

In System Preference/Security/Privacy/Automation after unlock you have to select Finder/System Events.

Then may be in Accessibility you can select Finder if you got an error.

There are some explanations : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/change-privacy-preferences-on-mac-mh32356/10.14/mac/10.14

Comment: I did go through that, but no joy. Thanks for the link anyway!

Comment: @Dave Evetitt. It's don't work?